# Spring REST for DELETE Request Method

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "processPurchase/{poid}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String processOrder(@PathVariable int poid) {
    // do some processing
    return acceptPurchaseForm;
}
```

My HTML

```
<form id="purchase-list-form" class="form-horizontal" action="/MyNewApp/processPurchase/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
<input type="hidden" name="poid" value="">
```

With the above I still get the following error

`WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'DELETE' not supported`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I assume you have the [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) configured in your web.xml. It is required to convert your `_method` with value delete to the DELETE RequestMethod

Secondly, the `poid` is being passed in the body of the request but in your controller, you are expecting it to be passed in the URL itself. This might explain why Spring is unable to map the request.

EDIT 1:

To pass `poid` in URL, you will have to include in your form action when your HTML is generated. It depends on your view technology (I use Freemarker) but you would be required to do something like this:

```
<form action="/MyNewApp/processPurchase/${poid}" method="post">
```

Assuming that the poid is written to the model that is binded to your view.

Comment: Can you show me sample on how to pass the parameter on the URL ?